# Java EJB Calling method after a delay

Tags: java, timer, ejb, delay

I have an stateless EJB with a method that should call different methods with a delay.
For example:

EJB 1

```
public void start()
{
   waitFor3Seconds();
   doSomething1();
   waitFor3Seconds();
   doSomething2();
   waitFor3Seconds();
   doSomething3();
}
```

How do I implement waitFor3Seconds() ?
I don't want to use Thread.sleep() because it blocks.

Comment: _Any_ method that you use for causing a delay will necessarily block execution, a stateless session EJB is strictly synchronous

Answer (score 4, accepted):

An EJB should not wait during processing, it smells like a bad design to me. Maybe you should consider asynchronous processing? (perhaps using an MDB). And please, resist the temptation of using `Thread.sleep()`, that's one of the [restrictions](http://java.sun.com/blueprints/qanda/ejb_tier/restrictions.html) of EJB development (emphasis mine):

> Specifically, enterprise beans should not (...) create or **manage threads**.

Another possibility would be to use a job scheduling framework (say, [Quartz](http://quartz-scheduler.org/)) for scheduling as many tasks as needed, setting the jobs to start one after the other at the times required by your process. In your example, three jobs would be needed: `doSomething1()`, `doSomething2()`, `doSomething3()`, configured to start with the required delays.

Answer (score 2):

Use the Timer Service provided by Java EE:

http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/tutorial/doc/bnboy.html#bnbpa

You need to see the section entitled "Creating Programmatic Timers"

Comment: I have tried creating a timer, but that isn't reusable, as the timer would always have the same onTimeout call, rather than a waitFor3Seconds() method.

Comment: Create 3 different timers, each that call doSomething1(), doSomething2(), doSomething3(). If the events are dependent, create the next timer within the previous timer.

Comment: This works, but does not scale.  It becomes unmanageable after 10+ timers.

Comment: how so? Your timers fire once and die.

Answer (score 0):

> How do I implement waitFor3Seconds() ? I don't want to use Thread.sleep() because it blocks.

Whatever waiting method you'll implement, your EJB will be blocked — by design it will return to the pool of free EJBs after your method has returned. This is why others suggested employing asynchronous processing.